# How to fit a model of Gaussian rise and exponential decay to data (lightcurves) in Python?

Tags: python, model, curve-fitting

I am trying to fit a model like this [Gaussian rise before peak and exponential decay after peak, see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UjEt8.png) to my lightcurve data.

How do I code this? Below is my initial attempt to fit one of gaussian
and  [here is the curve (blue) I'm trying to fit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUf6j.png)

How do I restrict gaussian function up till peak and exponential/power law from peak to end?

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import numpy as np
 
#Function to calculate the exponential decay with constants a and b
def exponential(x, a, b):
    return a*np.exp(-b*x)
 
#Function to calculate the power-law decay with constants a and b
def power_law(x, a, b):
    return a*np.power(-x, b)

# Function to calculate the Gaussian rise with constants a, b, and c
def gaussian(x, a, b, c):
    return a*np.exp(-np.power(x - b, 2)/(2*np.power(c, 2)))



# x and y data points    
xData = t_slice['time']
yData = t_slice['flux']/10**38 #normalizing


#Plot data points
plt.plot(xData, yData, 'b.', label='SED')
 

# Fit Gaussian
pars, cov = curve_fit(gaussian, xdata=xData, ydata=yData, p0=[0, 0, 0], bounds=(-np.inf, np.inf))
# Get the standard deviations of the parameters (square roots of the # diagonal of the covariance)
stdevs = np.sqrt(np.diag(cov))


#for xData in range(50,1000):
#popt, pcov = curve_fit(exponential, xData, yData)

print("parameters:",pars)
print("std dev:",stdevs)
#print(popt)
 
#x values for the fitted function
#xFit = np.arange(50, 1000, 0.01)
 


# Plot the fit data as an overlay on the scatter data
plt.scatter(xData, gaussian(xData, *pars), linestyle='--', linewidth=2, color='black')


#popt, pcov = curve_fit(exponential, xData, yData, bounds=(0, [30., 2., 0.5]))

plt.ylim(0, 1000)
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: if possible always include your images as images and not as links. this improves readability

Comment: @gerdadiegandalfziege yes I wanted to but I need some more points before the website allows me to

Comment: ...are you sure about the model? does not look like a gaussian in the beginning, more like x exp(-ax)

Comment: Why don't you joint your data (numerical) to your question ?

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing a bit, but what you show in the picture cannot be generated by the piecewise formula in the other picture. For `t > t_peak` the curve apparently shows a stretched exponential decay, not a simple exponential. Combining a gaussian peak with an exponential decay would give a kink at `t = t_peak`.

Defining a picewise function is easy, e.g.:

```
def piecewise(x, a, b, c, tau, beta):
    lower = (a*np.exp(-np.power(x - b, 2)/(2*np.power(c, 2)))) * (x < b)
    upper = a*np.exp(-np.power((x - b)/tau,beta)) * (x >= b)
    return lower+upper
```

(The key is to multiply with `x < b` and `x >= b`.)